# How do I change iBus input methods when the session is locked in KDE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, input-languages

How do I switch between input methods with iBus on the lock screen? Part of my work necessitates me using iBus for Chinese pinyin input. I had the misfortune of leaving the input method on pinyin while I went off to lunch, and the computer locked itself.

When I tried to log in, iBus took everything as a pinyin input and inserted Chinese instead into the password field. Ctrl-space didn't do anything. I had to start a new session and lost quite a bit of work.

I'm running KDE 4.13 over Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: There should be an icon with the language close to the password textbox  (it could appear as 2 letters of the layout). Click on it to change it. It depends from the display manager (kdm,gdm,xdm,lightdm...). Please [edit] your post adding this information. Ps> Welcome on Super User